# NAL unit loss software , packet loss , video

Tags: video, video-streaming, h.264, hevc, packet-loss

I'm trying to stream an HD video and insert loss to its packets.

I found "NAL Unit Loss Software" in references of papers that I were written about Hd video streaming. but I can't find this documente. it's removed !

is there anybody can help me to find this paper ? I hope this paper help me to promote my work.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Full details of the paper:
S. Wenger, “NAL Unit Loss Software” JCT-VC Document, JCTVCH0072, Feb. 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NAL unit loss software was included with earlier version of the HM reference software  (in the utils folder).

However, this software was never updated when the NAL unit structure changed in the HEVC standard and is no longer suitable for use without modification.